# How can I make an Upvote/Downvote button?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm trying to make an upvote/downvote the same way that it's done on SO and Reddit, from what I can see they use arrow images as backgrounds and then position it, but I'm a CSS newbie and I need someone to walk me through it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You could do it by adding a different picture to the background, one for every state of the button. There is however a cleaner, easier, more modern way of achieving this result: Sprites.

A sprite is an image that is saved as a part of a larger image. One of the biggest advantages of using sprites is the reduction of round-trips to the server for all the images to just one request for the Sprites. The element to display a picture has the image as background. The background is moved relative to the element so the element displays only part of the image. Like when you move a photo-frame over a poster (or in this case: moving the poster under the frame)

At SO they make an image that contains all the states for the button. They give the element for the button (a `span` in this case) a fixed width and height and add the background to it with CSS. Then toggle a class for the state (on or off) with javascript on the click event. Now the only thing you have to do in CSS is change the position of the background with CSS classes:

[image: The up/down sprite image]

```js
for (const btn of document.querySelectorAll('.vote')) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('on');
  });
}
```

```css
.vote {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqN2k.png');
  background-position: 0 -25px;
} 


.vote.on {
  background-position: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
Click to vote (using sprites): <span class="sprite vote"> </span>
```

You can easily add more states to the sprites like 'hover' and 'active' just the same way. SO even puts all the images for the whole page in a single image. You can verify this with firebug or the Chrome developer tools. Look for 'sprites.png'.

#### Update (2020)

It's been 10 years since I answered this question and in this time,
the landscape has changed. Now you can use inline svg as well to achieve this effect. I've updated the code snippet to use svg. This is how stackoverflow currently does this.

It works by toggling the color property of a surrounding span element on button click. The span element contains an inline svg image of an arrow. The `fill` property of the path that makes up the arrow is initialized with `currentColor`, which instructs it to take whatever is the current text color.

```js
for (const btn of document.querySelectorAll('.vote')) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('on');
  });
}
```

```css
.vote {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #687074
} 


.vote.on {
  color: #f48024
}
```

```html
Click to vote (using svg): 
<span class="vote">
  <svg width="36" height="36">
    <path d="M2 10h32L18 26 2 10z" fill="currentColor"></path>
  </svg>
</span>
```

Comment: +1 The technique is called CSS Sprites and provides better performance than the alternative, which is to have a separate image for each button state. You will probably want to add all four states into one image then change the background as Jan specified.

Comment: Yes, but for this application it is pretty basic. You should learn the basics anyway if you want to develop for the web.

Comment: How would you incorporate a downvote option? A second sprite?

Comment: @DavidWeisser you would add two more sprites for the downvote button in the same image and use the same technique to position the background in a way that it toggles between those two states. Alternatively you can use inline svg to achieve the same effect , I updated the answer to include that technique (SO has been updated in the meantime to use this technique)

Comment: Can you add the svg path for the upvote >

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by using two simple images ... design two images in some image editors like Photoshop, if u don't have MSPaint...

CSS code is

```
#voting{
   width:30px;
   height:40px;
}
.upvote{
   width:30px;
   height: 20px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.downvote{
   width:30px;
   height: 20px;
   background: url('downvote.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML code :

```
<div id="voting">
    <div class="upvote"></div>
    <div class="downvote"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing project on django, and I'm trying to implement up-vote and down-vote on many posts, I've taken @Jan's code partly and finished it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

`vote.html`

```
<span onclick="like_function({{user_answer.pk}})" id="like-{{user_answer.pk}}" class="vote_up_off"></span>
<div id="counter-{{user_answer.pk}}">0</div>
<span onclick="dislike_function({{user_answer.pk}})" id="dislike-{{user_answer.pk}}" class="vote_down_off"></span>
```

`vote.css`

```
/* like dislike button */
.vote_up_off {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(' https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxBdX.png');
  background-position: 0 -25px;
  margin-left: 5px;
} 

.vote_up_on {
  background-position: 0 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxBdX.png');
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.vote_down_off {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWw7n.png');
  background-position: 0 -1px;
  margin-top: 3px;
} 


.vote_down_on {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWw7n.png');
  background-position: 0 -28px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

`vote.js`

```
function like_function(answer_id) {
    var like_button = document.getElementById('like-'+answer_id);
    var dislike_button = document.getElementById('dislike-'+answer_id);
    var counter_element = document.getElementById('counter-'+answer_id);
    let current_counter = parseInt(counter_element.innerText);

    //check if dislike is on(true) or off(false)
    let dislike_state = false
    if (dislike_button.className == "vote_down_on") {
        dislike_state = true
    }
    else {
        dislike_state = false
    }
    //if dislike is checked
    if (dislike_state) {
        current_counter += 2;
        dislike_button.className = 'vote_down_off'
        counter_element.innerText = current_counter
        like_button.className = 'vote_up_on'
    }
    // if dislike is not checked
    else {
        if (like_button.className == 'vote_up_off') {
            like_button.className = "vote_up_on"
            current_counter +=  1;
            counter_element.innerText = current_counter
        }
        else {
            like_button.className = "vote_up_off"
            current_counter +=  -1;
            counter_element.innerText = current_counter
        }
    }
}



function dislike_function(answer_id) {
    var like_button = document.getElementById('like-'+answer_id);
    var dislike_button = document.getElementById('dislike-'+answer_id);
    var counter_element = document.getElementById('counter-'+answer_id);
    let current_counter = parseInt(counter_element.innerText);

    //check if like is on(true) or off(false)
    let like_state = false
    if (like_button.className == "vote_up_on") {
        like_state = true
    }
    else {
        like_state = false
    }
    //if like is checked
    if (like_state) {
        console.log('это тру лайк (лайк нажат)')
        current_counter +=  -2;
        like_button.className = 'vote_up_off'
        counter_element.innerText = current_counter
        dislike_button.className = "vote_down_on"
    }
    //if like is not checked
    else {
        if (dislike_button.className == 'vote_down_off') {
            dislike_button.className = "vote_down_on"
            current_counter +=  -1;
            counter_element.innerText = current_counter
        }
        else {
            dislike_button.className = "vote_down_off"
            current_counter +=  1;
            counter_element.innerText = current_counter
        }
    }
}
```