# How do i create a vote up down button, like stackoverflow, in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

I know this question is repeated, but the question which exists is w.r.t to PYTHON.
My question is with respect to RUBY ON RAILS.

So please help.

Thanks
Krishna Kumar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4274489/419436 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Ajax...ROR has a range of Ajax helpers.  Link to remote will allow you to update a score server side without a page refresh.  Have a look at:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html

And try it out.

Slotishtype

Comment: Thank you very much slotishtype