# How to use jquery with my Node.js EJS template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js

**SITUATION:**

I am trying to implement the first answer (with 25 upvotes) to this question: [How can I make an Upvote/Downvote button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274489/how-can-i-make-an-upvote-downvote-button) with my Node.js ejs template.

So I wrote this code.

---

**MY CODE:**

Main.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$('.UpvoteButton').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('on');
});

$('.DownvoteButton').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('on');
});
```

style.css

```
.UpvoteButton {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url('/assets/UpvoteButtonSpriteSheet.png');
    background-position: 0 0px;
}

.DownvoteButton {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url('/assets/DownvoteButtonSpriteSheet.png');
    background-position: 0 0px;
}

.UpvoteButton.on {
  background-position: 0 50px;
}

.DownvoteButton.on {
  background-position: 0 50px;
}
```

index.ejs

```
<% include ../partials/header %>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class ="containerMarginsIndex">

        <% for(var i=0; i < fun.length; i++) {%>
            <div class="fun">
                <h3 class="text-left"><%= fun[i].title %></h3>
                <a href="details/<%= fun[i].id %>">
                    <img class = "postImg" src="/images/uploads/<%= fun[i].image %>">
                </a>
                <span class="UpvoteButton"> </span><span class="DownvoteButton"> </span>

            </div>
        <% } %>

</div>
<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

---

**PROBLEM:**

Nothing happens when I click. The images stay the same.

---

**QUESTION:**

What have I done wrong ?

Comment: "with Node.js" - what exactly does than mean ? That you are using Express for example ? Can you paste you source code - as source generated and 'seen' by the browser ?

Comment: jQuery is available for Node.js through NPM, but generally you don't need it on the server *(or on the client for that matter)*. There's no document, nor anything to click, on a webserver, and there's usually no `require` on the clientside, unless you're using Browserify or Webpack. In other words, you're most likely doing it wrong.

Comment: @adeneo I am using ejs to render my pages (as the index.ejs suggests). In my index.js, I have 2 spans which contain clickable images. As said, I am trying to replicate the behaviour in the linked answer. If I am doing it wrong, please tell me why and how I can remedy to the situation :) Thank you !

Comment: @marcinrek It means I am exclusively using npm modules to render my pages (I am using ejs). Just looking to add some clickable functionality to 2 spans in one of my ejs files. Express is one of the modules I am using, yes.

Comment: The link you've posted doesn't seem to use anything like `require('jquery')`, but a regular script tag. You have clientside code, that works with the DOM, and clicks, and you probably need a regular plain old script tag that includes jQuery in the browser, and another script tag for that clientside code of yours, as it's not going to magically appear even if you use EJS.

Comment: @adeneo Ok, I see. Where should I include the script tag ? And where should I put the jquery code ? Currently learning Node.js, sorry if my questions seem obvious  :) Also, could you please formulate what you are about to write in an answer to the question so I can accept it and upvote it ?

Comment: @Coder1000 well in that case adeneo is right. Long story short - add jQuery as a part of your template as well as this Main.js (just without the require line)

Comment: You'd put it in `index.ejs`, the file that is being rendered and sent to the browser

Comment: @adeneo I just tried. Didn't work :( Let me edit my code with your suggestion.

Comment: @adeneo All right, I updated my code to show what I tried based on your suggestion. I must have misunderstood something since it doesn't work :(

Comment: @adeneo How about you answer my question with a formal answer that includes my code but modified the way it should be ? Like that, there can be no misunderstanding on my part :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/da1nk1s2/

Comment: @adeneo Great ! That did it. Please post this as your answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to include jQuery and the clientside script in your EJS template, so it's rendered in the browser.

Installing jQuery with npm in Node, and doing `var $ = require('jquery')` on the serverside, just lets you use some of jQuery's methods on the server, it doesn't include jQuery on the clientside.

Change the template to something like

```
<% include ../partials/header %>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class ="containerMarginsIndex">

        <% for(var i=0; i < fun.length; i++) {%>
            <div class="fun">
                <h3 class="text-left"><%= fun[i].title %></h3>
                <a href="details/<%= fun[i].id %>">
                    <img class = "postImg" src="/images/uploads/<%= fun[i].image %>">
                </a>
                <span class="UpvoteButton"> </span><span class="DownvoteButton"> </span>

            </div>
        <% } %>

</div>
<script>
    $('.UpvoteButton').click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('on');
      $('.DownvoteButton').removeClass('on');
    });

    $('.DownvoteButton').click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('on');
      $('.UpvoteButton').removeClass('on');
    });
</script>
<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

Answer (score 4):

the browser does not support require command natively. you have to use a file bundler like webpack or browserify in order to include the "jquery.js" file in your main js file.

Comment: Not what I was looking to do, but thanks ! I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced similar issue in NodeJS using the ejs as the 'view engine' template, and resolved it as bellow:

#### Server side:

1. Install jQuery and jsdom:

   ```
   npm install jquery --save
   npm install jsdom --save
   ```
2. For jQuery to work in Node, a window with a document is required. Since no such window exists natively in Node, one can be mocked by tools such as jsdom
   and as of v10, jsdom has a new API and you can configure jsdom in your server side code (i.e. app.js or index.js) as below:

   ```
   var jsdom = require("jsdom");
   const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
   const { window } = new JSDOM();
   const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
   global.document = document;
   var $ = require("jquery")(window);
   ```

#### Client side:

1. Include jQuery package as usual in the ejs template (e.g. header.ejs):

   ```
   <head>
       <title>Whatever App</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   ```
2. Then the js scripts that you put in the ejs file will be rendered without any problem, for example, in your case, just put the js script in the 
   index.ejs:

   ```
   <script>
        $('.UpvoteButton').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('on');
            $('.DownvoteButton').removeClass('on');
        });

        $('.DownvoteButton').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('on');
            $('.UpvoteButton').removeClass('on');
        });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: I hope the edition suits you. Otherwise, you can rollback to your version ;)

Comment: But still, it is not possible to use JQUERY from an external file in the EJS file? I wrote some JQUERY and it works perfectly when write it in the .ejs file, but as soon as I move the code to a .js file it doesn't work. I added the script also with <script src="/jqscript.js"></script>. In the .js file I call it with: $(document).on('ready' , function() {   
.... }); But it doesn't react. When I call it on the Client side. Any tipps? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for my english.
I know this post is old but I have the same issue and I finded a solution.
It's possible to use an external JQuery file.
It must be placed into "public" folder.

**With this tree :**
application.js
[views]
    index.ejs
[public]
    [include]
        jquery.min.js
        fonctions_jquery.js

**With this code in "index.js"** :

```
<script src="/include/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/include/fonctions_jquery.js"></script>
```

**With this code in "application.js"**

```
var express =   require('express');
var path    = require('path');

var appli = express();
appli.use(express.static(__dirname +path.sep+ 'public'));
```

It works for me.